# Expanding variable number of columns in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that can have a varying number of columns and I need to expand each column out automatically two more times before the next one:

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=2:11,c=3:12)
df
```

I tried

```
dfexpand <- df[,rep(colnames(df),3)]
dfexpand
```

But this gives the columns in the order in this case:

```
a  b  c a.1 b.1 c.1 a.2 b.2 c.2
```

But I need the order in this case as:

```
a a.1 a.2 b b.1 b.2 c c.1 c.2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the `each` argument to `rep()`:

```
dfexpand <- df[,rep(colnames(df),each=3)]
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks very much.